# Tau Numbers Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to make a program where a user enters 2 numbers, and then the program gives the tau numbers in this gap.

- "Tau" number is the number which can divided by its  total number of dividers.For example (1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24) all this numbers can divide 24. There is 8 numbers then 24 can divided by 8. So we can say 24 is a tau number.*

There is a mistake at second for loop I think but I cannot understand where is it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tauNumber {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        int start=0,stop=0,count=0;
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter first number: ");
        start=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter last number: ");
        stop=input.nextInt();

        for(int i=0+start;i<=stop;i++){

            for(int j=1;j<=start;j++){
                if(i%j==0){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(start/count==0){
                System.out.println(i+" is a tau number" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "tau number" exactly? But my guess is that you forgot to reinitialize `count` to 0 at the start of the for loop.

Comment: @Tunaki [Apparently a constant](http://tauday.com/tau-digits) like `e` and `pi`.

Comment: @px06 Actually, [it is a number divisible by the number of its divisors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RefactorableNumber.html). Tau is also 2 * pi, but that's different here.

Comment: @Tunaki Looking over the google results, it's quite ambiguous as to what it is. [Most of it is being compared to pi](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1292:_Pi_vs._Tau).

Comment: @Tunaki  For example (1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24) all this numbers can divide 24. There is 8 numbers then 24 can divided by 8. So we can say 24 is a tau number.

Comment: Yes, thanks for confirming. Take a look at my first comment: `count` should be set to 0 at the start of the `for(int i=0+start;i<=stop;i++)` loop.

Comment: `start/count==0` can be true only when `start ==0`

Comment: @tbcse Welcome to SO. Please update your question to provide a definition for "tau" numbers so future viewers of this question are not confused.

Comment: @Tunaki  I've tried it but compiler stopped.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry Is it true like this ?

Comment: @tbcse Yes, that is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saying "tau number" you should just refer to it as a [refactorable number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RefactorableNumber.html) as @Tunaki pointed out.

I would suggest that you split your code up into functions to get a better understanding on whats going on, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TauNumber {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter first number: ");
        int start=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter last number: ");
        int stop=input.nextInt();

        for(int i=start+1; i<stop; i++){
            if(refractorable(i)){
                System.out.println("Found tau number: "+ i);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean refractorable(int number){
        if(sumDivisors(number) == 0) return false; 

        if(number % sumDivisors(number) == 0){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int sumDivisors(int number){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<=number; i++){
            if(number % i == 0){
                sum++;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }


}
```

Note: I would also like to point out that when you specify "gap" what do you mean by it? I took it as `start < x < stop`, because that would be the gap but it could certainly be `start < x <= stop`.

Comment: I mean that start <  x < stop but you are right it must be x <= stop. It still works ,thank you so much.

Comment: @tbcse yeah it can be important to note that, I would like to stress that the reason for me to post this code is mainly so you can get more used to splitting your code up into functions and doing things. It helps a lot with debugging and reading and you'll find that it helps with re-usability.

Answer (score 1):

The fault in your code is that you check whether the **quotient** of `start/count` is `0`. To check whether `start` is divisible by `count`, you should check whether the **remainder** is `0`. Therefore, you should use the modulus (`%`) operator instead of the division (`/`) operator.

Below is a function's code that checks whether its argument is a tau number.

```
private static boolean isTau(int tau){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=tau; i++){
        if(tau % i == 0)
            count++;
    }
    return (tau % count == 0) ; //returns true if 'tau' is a tau number
}
```

In the main method, you can make use of this function like this:

```
for(int i=start; i<=stop; i++){
    if(isTau(i))
        System.out.println(i+" is a tau number");
}
```

Comment: I've already seen your code in your question. Why paste it here??

Comment: I've changed my first code and it is working now.I pasted it because other people will maybe use it.Final type of it is more short and useful that's why.